# Can anyone help me on using GUI page in intelliJ

Tags: user-interface

Need some help on GUI form
I am trying to use it for excel read and write

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadExcel read = new ReadExcel();

```
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
    String line = null;
    String name= null;
    String INPUT_FILE_LOCATION = null;
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
    // int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        INPUT_FILE_LOCATION = br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            name= line;
            names.add(line);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("name is:::" + name);
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
        System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    read.getData(INPUT_FILE_LOCATION, IS_SERVICES);
    System.out.println("IS_SERVICES::: " + IS_SERVICES.size());
```

Comment: Thanx for the response let you know if it works